# How to disable download for chrome headless using start up flag

Tags: google-chrome-headless

I am using google chrome headless for some crawling.

When crawler visit page with file like this: `www.example.com/file.zip` file is downloaded, I don't want to downloaded file. Is there any way how to disable download in start up flags? Or some other way?